# Recursive lazy seq in Clojure

Tags: recursion, clojure, lazy-evaluation

I can't understand why this lazy-seq causes a stackoverflow, and why not when you pass the sequence to dorun:

```
(defn very-lazy [s]
    (lazy-seq
   (if (seq s)
     [(first s) (very-lazy (rest s))]
     [])))

(dorun (very-lazy (range 200000000)))
>nil

(take 2 (very-lazy (range 20000000))
>...(1577 (java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

If it's lazy then `take 2` should cause the lazy seq to iterate only two times, why doesn't happen and why dorun works?

Answer (score 3):

In your example function returns lazyseq `(0 (1 (2 (3 (...)))))`. That's why `dorun` runs without stackoverflow (there is sequence of two elements `0` and `(1 (2 (...)))` that `dorun` doesn't evaluate) and `second` fails (it returns infinite nested sequences that repl tries evaluate to print out).

I guess you're looking for this solution

```
(defn very-lazy [s]
  (lazy-seq
   (if (seq s)
     (cons (first s) (very-lazy (rest s)))
     [])))

(take 10 (very-lazy (range 200000000)))
-> (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
```

Comment: Evaluating lazy seqs in the REPL often causes problems trying to print the results that would not occur in normal usage, e.g. just typing `(repeat 1)` in the REPL is a bad idea.

Comment: You can set `*print-length*` to limit output, e.g. for `(set! *print-length* 10)` `(repeat 1)` will be outputted as `(1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...)` in repl.